# Query records in JavaScript

Tags: soql, javascript

How to write the below SOQL Query in JavaSCript

SOQL Query:

```
select  Country,CountryCode,Latitude,Longitude  from Lead Where (Latitude!=null or  Longitude!=null) AND Country= 'IN'
```

In JavaSCript:I have tried to implement the above SOQL in JavaSCript,But It's not working .Can anyone help me

```
 var a='IN';
 var strQuery="SELECT Name, Id,Latitude,Longitude,Country from Lead where Country =\'"+ a + "\'+" AND (Latitude!=null or  Longitude!=null) limit 10";
   var result = sforce.connection.query(strQuery);
```

> Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at
>       `AND (Latitude!=null or Longitude!=null)`

Comment: usually, when you say not working, there is an error message associated to it, after you have id'd the error, you should be able to identify the root cause and correct it (or at least try)

Comment: Thanks, It is throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at  AND (Latitude!=null or  Longitude!=null) limit 10";

Comment: please update your post accordingly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've an extra `+"` before `AND`. Can you try the below one?

```
var a='IN';
var strQuery = "SELECT Id,Name,Latitude,Longitude,Country from Lead where Country =\'"+ a + "\' and (Latitude!=null or  Longitude!=null) limit 10";
var result = sforce.connection.query(strQuery);
```

Hope this helps.